# DotNetBrowser call javascript function to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, dotnetbrowser

I have this JS code which I use to display both street view and google maps in my form:

```js
/*
       * Click the map to set a new location for the Street View camera.
       */
var icon;
var markers = [];
var currentmarker;
var geocoder, infowindow;
var map;
var panorama;
var sv;

function initMap() {
    var berkeley = { lat: 39.277782, lng: -7.428514 };
    sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));
    // Set up the map.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: berkeley,
        zoom: 17,
        streetViewControl: false
    });
    sv.getPanorama({ location: berkeley, radius: 70 }, processSVData);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    map.addListener('click', function (event) {
        sv.getPanorama({ location: event.latLng, radius: 70 }, processSVData);
    });
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var input = document.getElementById("resulttest");     /*latlng*/
        var latlngStr = input.value.split(',', 2);
        geocodeLatLng(latlngStr);
    });
    // Set the initial Street View camera to the center of the map
    // Look for a nearby Street View panorama when the map is clicked.
    // getPanoramaByLocation will return the nearest pano when the
    // given radius is 50 meters or less.

}

function geocodeLatLng(latlngStr) {
    // var input = document.getElementById("resulttest");     /*latlng*/
    latlngStr = latlngStr.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };
    geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[1]) {
                center: latlng,
                    map.setZoom(20);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                sv.getPanorama({ location: latlng, radius: 70 }, processSVData);
            } else {
                window.alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
function processSVData(data, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: data.location.latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.location.description
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
        panorama.setPov({
            heading: 270,
            pitch: 0
        });
        panorama.setVisible(true);
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
            // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID.
            panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: 270,
                pitch: 0
            });
            panorama.setVisible(true);
        });
    } else {
        console.error('Street View data not found for this location.');
    }
}

function OnclickMarker(data, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
        panorama.setPov({
            heading: 270,
            pitch: 0
        });
        panorama.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        console.error('Street View data not found for this location.');
    }
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
function clearOverlays() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
}

function showMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(map);
}

function criarMarker(id, lat, lon) {
    alert(id + '   ' + lat + ' ' + lon);
    var LatLng = { lat: lat, lng: lon };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: id,
        position: LatLng,
        map: map
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        this.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
        sv.getPanorama({ location: LatLng, radius: 70 }, OnclickMarker);
        if (currentmarker != null) {
            currentmarker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');
            panorama.setPov({
                heading: 165,
                pitch: 0
            });
        }
        currentmarker = this;



        //alert(lat);
        //var evente = document.createEvent('MessageEvent');
        //    var origina = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
        //evente = new MessageEvent('jsCall', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': 'criarMarker' });
        //document.dispatchEvent(evente);


        var evente = document.createEvent('MessageEvent');
        var origina = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
        evente = new MessageEvent('jsCall', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': id });
        document.dispatchEvent(evente);

    });

}
```

I would like to call function "criarMarker" and that little guy "jscall", but I am not able to do it. Tried using: `browser.ExecuteJavaScript("criarMarker('" + item.id + "'," + item.lat + "," + item.lon + ");");` and when I run the program it shows the output in image:

[image: This output]

but doesn't add the markers in the map. Any ideas? Appreciate the effort!

EDIT *Plus Info*: According my answer I'm actually in need of help calling "jsCall", previously I used geckobrowser and used "AddMessageEventListener" in my c#, but now its seems that I cannot call it `geckoWebBrowser1.AddMessageEventListener("jsCall", (id) =>` this is what I used in my previous code.

Another Edit: I changed the last 4 lines of my JS to make it a function and now looks like this:

```
function newFunction(evente, id) {
evente = new MessageEvent('jsCall', { 'view': window, 'bubbles': false, 'cancelable': false, 'data': id });
return evente;
```

Also if this is confusing the whole point is when I press the marker it changes my dgv row. But nothing is really happening and I really don't know why, my code for the dgv is this one:

```
                    int rowindex = -1;
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Cells["Edificio_cad"].Value.ToString().Equals(id))
                    {

                        rowindex = row.Index;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Selected = true;
                        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowindex;
                        //MessageBox.Show(edificios);
                        //Console.WriteLine(edificios);
                        MessageBox.Show(lat);
                        return;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    }
                }
```

Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I added this and worked

```
  browser.FinishLoadingFrameEvent += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.IsMainFrame)
            {
                foreach (var item in edificios)
                {
                    browser.ExecuteJavaScript("criarMarker('" + item.id + "'," + item.lat + "," + item.lon + ");");

                }
                //browser.ExecuteJavaScript("jsCall");
            }
        };
```

Now I need to cal this "jsCall" one. If I can do it, I'll add to this answer aswell!

Comment: Perhaps, this article will be helpful in your case. It contains the sample which demonstrates how to embedding and displaying Google Maps in the application using DotNetBrowser: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000110651-dotnetbrowser-google-maps

Comment: Hello @VladyslavTsvek in my case I already a have pre-loaded markers, I need to get the id's and match them with my datagridview row.